# A difficult Vietnamese university entrance exam problem minimize/maximize $P = \frac{x}{{2x + 3y}} + \frac{y}{{y + z}}+\frac{z}{{z + x}}$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, optimization

A difficult problem from the Vietnamese Entrance exam of 2011 for Natural Science and Technology group.

Note that the original problem only involve minimization.

> How to minimize and maximize $P = \frac{x}{{2x + 3y}} + \frac{y}{{y + z}} + \frac{z}{{z + x}}$ when $x,y,z \in \left[ {1,4} \right]$, $x \geqslant y$ and $x \geqslant z$?

The answer to the maximization problem is $P = \frac{6}{5}$ when $x = y$.
A nice solution without Lagrange multipliers/calculus is preferred, just like the solution for the minimization problem in @Toby Mak's link.

The answer to the minimization problem is $P = \frac{{34}}{{33}}$ when $x = 4,y = 1,z = 2$ but the approach from the official government answer sheet was quite unfair.

To be particular, solving by knowing the answer before hand. It requires student to first proof something from thin air into existence
$\frac{1}{{1 + a}} + \frac{1}{{1 + b}} \geqslant \frac{2}{{1 + \sqrt {ab} }}$.

Comment: What was the answer for the minimum? (just curious)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the minimum value of $\frac{x}{2x+3y}+\frac{y}{y+z}+\frac{z}{z+x}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59814/how-to-find-the-minimum-value-of-fracx2x3y-fracyyz-fraczzx) Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz).

Comment: The attached file in [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h416261p2344106) does not use calculus.

Comment: @TobyMak Note the post here also asks for the maximum value.  In fact the minimum was mentioned to be the subject of the contest question.  [So it isn't a duplicate]

Comment: I also asked for the maximum guys :)

Comment: @TobyMak It is not a duplicate since the question asks for maximum.

Comment: I've voted to reopen the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The maximization problem*:

Since $P$ is homogeneous, WLOG, assume $x = 4$.

If $y = 4$, then $P = \frac{6}{5}$ for any $z$.

Indeed, $\frac65$ is the maximum of $P$, since
\begin{align*}
 P &= \frac{4}{8 + 3y} + \frac{y}{y + z} + \frac{z}{z + 4}\\
 &= \frac{6}{5} - \frac{(4 - y)[3(z - 1)(4y - z) + 25z]}{5(8 + 3y)(y + z)(z + 4)}\\
 &\le \frac{6}{5}
\end{align*}
with equality if and only if $y = 4$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your approach ? where does $6/5$ comes from ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh I added something.

Comment: How to define homogeneous ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh Here, $P(\alpha x, \alpha y, \alpha z) = P(x, y, z)$ for $\alpha > 0$. For example, $x = 3, y= 2, z = 1$, let $\alpha = \frac{4}{3}$, then $P(\alpha x, \alpha y, \alpha z) = P(4, \frac{8}{3}, \frac{4}{3}) = P(3, 2, 1)$. So, WLOG, assume that $x = 4$.

Comment: Oh this is the first time I heard of this property. Do you know any source of material that provide a deeper insight or structural exploitation into the study of homogeneous property of polynomial or optimization problem ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh I have no idea about deeper insight.